# elementary probability question ( covariance)

Tags: probability-theory

I have some problem understanding a basic results in probability theory.
I have this definition for covariance  $ cov(X, Y ) = E_{fX,Y} ((X − E_{fX}(X))(Y − E_{fY}(Y ))= E_{fX,Y} (XY − X* E_{fY}(Y ) − Y* E_{fX}(X) + E_{fX}(X)*E_{fY}(Y ))= E_{fX,Y} (XY ) − E_{fY}
(Y )*E_{fX,Y} (X) − **EfX(X)EfX,Y (Y ) + EfX(X)EfY(Y )**(cancel out)
= E_{fX,Y} (XY ) − E_{fX}(X)*E_{fY}(Y )
$, which has the subscript ${f X,Y}$ , so it is a bivariate (joimt) distribution (right?)
But then i saw a proof of the fact that if X,Y are independent, then$Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$, so here the subscript would be ${f X+Y}$ (the sum of the two random variables)right?
I do not understand why it is the same thing, even if we use different subscripts(probability functions). Thank you

Comment: What are $fX$ and $fY$?

Comment: @zoli :probability mass functions.

Comment: Advice: Cancel every such subscript and forget them, you will get correct formulas and you will stop be bothered by absurd and unnecessary notations.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I will do so. But just to clarify this problem, can you also give me a hint for this problem? thanks

Comment: You mean, to explain why $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)$ is $$E((X-E(X))(Y-E(Y)))=E(XY-XE(Y)-YE(X)+E(X)E(Y))=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$$ right? Well, the first expression can be taken as the definition, the first $=$ sign is the expansion of the product in the expectation and the last $=$ sign uses the linearity of the expectation, which makes for example that $E(E(X)Y)=E(X)E(Y)$.